# Image Stream Doesn't Stop

Tags: angular

I have an Angular app that streams images from an API. The image stream content type is: multipart/x-mixed-replace;boundary=frame.

Below is the html template I've used and it displays the streaming images correctly.

```
<a class="camera" href="#" 
   *ngFor="let camera of cameras" 
   (click)="selectCamera(camera)">
   <img src="{{camera.source}}" />
   <span class="camera-name">{{ camera.title }}</span>
</a>
```

The `cameras` is an object array containing both a title and source. It looks something like this:

```
export interface Camera {
  title: string;
  source: string;
}

cameras: Camera[] = [
    {
       title: "Stream 1", source: "http://localhost/stream1"   
    },
    {
       title: "Stream 2", source: "http://localhost/stream2"   
    },
    {
       title: "Stream 3", source: "http://localhost/stream3"   
    },
    {
       title: "Stream 4", source: "http://localhost/stream4"   
    }
]
```

My issue is when I set the cameras array to empty. The image stream stops displaying but from the web browser's developer mode (network tab) the stream doesn't stop and continues indefinitely.

How do I make the stream stop?

Comment: I' think there is an observable behind the scene that fetches the data. You must unsubscribe from it. use the unsubscribe() method

Comment: There's no observable involved. Basically camera.source contains the url to the image stream.

Comment: Indeed, you are making a server push communication. The server will not stop sending the data. Can you try to reload the page? And also try with different browsers. It's not supported by all browsers

Comment: My point is, when i set this.cameras = [], shouldn't the stream stop?

Comment: No because you have opened a persistent connection by using the multipart/x-mixed-replace header.

Comment: Can you advise how I can close this connection from Angular?

Comment: When you set the content type to multipart/x-mixed-replace;boundary=frame, you have attached this header to a http request? Can you unsubsribe from this request ? Or add the http request on the post

Comment: If you could, refer to this stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-vamwrc?file=src/app/app.component.ts 

When you are in the browser Developer Tools > Network, Press the stop button and you'll see that the stream continues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do something like that to close the communication

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  ngOnInit(): void {
    if (localStorage.getItem('load') == 'true') {
      this.cameras ==
        [
          {
            title: 'Cam 1',
            source: 'http://imagestream.wheregot.com/image/480/cam1',
          },
          {
            title: 'Cam 2',
            source: 'http://imagestream.wheregot.com/image/480/cam2',
          },
        ];
    }
  }
  cameras: camera[];

  stop() {
    localStorage.setItem('load', 'false');
    location.reload();
  }

  start() {
    localStorage.setItem('load', 'true');
    location.reload();
  }
}
```

HTML

```
<button (click)="stop()">Stop</button>
<button (click)="start()">start</button>

<div *ngFor="let camera of cameras">
  <img [src]="camera.source" />
  <span>{{ camera.title }}</span>
</div>
```

I could not test because the images you posted are not loading

Comment: `location.reload()` does the trick! Its a hack for sure but it works. Thanks so much for your time.